# insert multiple items value from listBox to one column using c# linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i have this list to BindListBox Value & text

```
private void BindDays()
        {
            List<dynamic> CreateDataSource = new List<dynamic>() {
            new { Name = "1", Value="1" },
            new { Name = "2", Value="2" },
            new { Name = "3", Value="3" },
            new { Name = "4", Value="4" },
            new { Name = "5", Value="5" },
            new { Name = "6", Value="6" }

            };

            List1.DataSource = CreateDataSource;
            List1.DataTextField = "Name";
            List1.DataValueField = "Value";
            List1.DataBind();
        }
```

and my method to insert data into MyTable

```
 private void Create()
            {
                TM_TEST tM_TEST = new TM_TEST();
                tM_TEST .Number= List1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                db.tM_TEST .Add(tM_TEST );
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

But the problem she give me a error
please someone  have any solytion thanks .

Comment: But the problem she give me a error..... and the error is

Comment: @BryanDellinger 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Use List1.SelectedValue.ToString()

Comment: `List1.SelectedItem` is probably null, add `if (!(List1.SelectedItem is null))` around the whole `Create` implementation

Comment: @vc74 ok i try now thanks

Comment: @vc74 is not give me a error great but not inserting data into table ??

Comment: @mehdi Looks like no item has been selected

Comment: @vc74 yes bro but i selected items from my listBox

Comment: @mehdi Multiple items, then you can't use `SelectedItem`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < List1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (List1.Items[i].Selected == true)
    {
        listItems += List1.Items[i].Value + ",";
    }
}
```